# Sugar ORM 1.4 E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: COURTS

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, sugarorm

For some reaso SUgar ORM is not creatingg my entities. I have tried to disable intant run, increased the DB version, uninstall the app completely but non seems to be working. I am using sugar ORM version 1.4. here is the error log that I get

```
07-07 21:48:01.575 31907-31907/com.globalsites.lms E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: COURTS
07-07 21:48:01.577 31907-31907/com.globalsites.lms D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-07 21:48:01.578 31907-31907/com.globalsites.lms E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.globalsites.lms, PID: 31907
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.globalsites.lms/com.globalsites.lms.Unsubscribed.UnsubscribedMainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: COURTS (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO COURTS(TYPE,ID,NAME,LOCATION) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2539)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:183)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1485)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5668)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:963)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)
                                                                      Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: COURTS (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO COURTS(TYPE,ID,NAME,LOCATION) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1499)
                                                                         at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:266)
                                                                         at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:360)
                                                                         at com.globalsites.lms.Unsubscribed.UnsubscribedMainActivity.onCreate(UnsubscribedMainActivity.java:102)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6155)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2486)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:183) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1485) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5668) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:963) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758) 
07-07 21:48:01.591 31907-31907/com.globalsites.lms I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31907 SIG: 9
```

The class entity:

```
package com.globalsites.lms.Models;

import com.orm.SugarRecord;

/**
 * Created by muoki on 7/7/2016.
 */
public class Courts extends SugarRecord {
    String name, location, type;

    public Courts() {
    }

    public Courts(String name, String location, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

The manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/lms_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon"
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">
        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="sugar_glms.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.globalsites.lms" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="Login" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="Register">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".LoginActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Unsubscribed.UnsubscribedMainActivity"
            android:label="Welcome to LMS"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

And this is how am trying to create a record

```
 Courts newCourt = new Courts("Milimani Law Courts","Nairobi","supreme");
        newCourt.save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the version of sugar ORM. I tried changing the DB version and it didnt work but as soon as I changed the sugar ORM from 1.4 to 1.5, it worked

Answer (score 0):

SugarORM has some strange problem with `VERSION`. Try to remove the whole app, change `VERSION` to `2` a try again. It helped me.

Comment: Another user mentioned this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292116/sugarorm-error-or-missing-database/39514488#39514488. I've used version 1 repeatedly with no side effects, did changing the version actually help you?

Comment: @Jake Yes, it helped me. SugarORM was unable to create just one simple table with two columns. After i removed everything from AVD emulator, changed db version to 2 and everything was fine.