# SugarORM error or missing database

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, sugarorm

I have tried to get an Android Project working with SugarORM. However, I am running into the following error:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: DOCUMENT (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO DOCUMENT(ID,CREATED) VALUES (?,?)
>                                                                           #################################################################
>                                                                           Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
>                                                                           Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
>                                                                               (no such table: DOCUMENT (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO DOCUMENT(ID,CREATED) VALUES (?,?))
>                                                                           #################################################################

In my AndroidManifest I have defined the `android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"` in my application - Tag and included

```
 <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="idea.db" />
 <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="1" />
```

also as child tags. I have removed

```
<meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
<meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.example" />
```

from the [example](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html) as they don't change anything ([and others had success in removing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031570/android-sugar-orm-no-such-table-exception)). I have tried to Query the db first (with findById) to "force table creation" as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792152/sugar-orm-no-such-table-exeption). Furthermore, I have tried doing something like

```
 SugarDb sugarDb = new SugarDb(getApplicationContext()); new
 File(sugarDb.getDB().getPath())
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031570/android-sugar-orm-no-such-table-exception).But this runs in an error as well. Furthermore I have disabled the InstantRun-Feature as described in a few posts and here ([Sugar ORM No such table exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792152/sugar-orm-no-such-table-exeption)).

Can anybody point me the right direction how to get rid of the "error or missing database"-error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `<meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.example" />` doesn't change anything? Your link supporting that doesn't seem to go to the correct place. Regardless, follow the examples until the issue is fixed, then worry about what can be trimmed away!

You shouldn't need to be looking at the database file, not really sure why that's included.

Does your Document class extends SugarRecord? Without that, the table won't be created.

In general I think you should try running through the "Getting Started" again from scratch, without making any modifications to the code on the way.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and in my case, it turned out that sugar orm version 1.4 had issues. Just update your gradle dependency to `compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'` This solved my problem

Comment: Have the same problem also with 1.5

Comment: Try increment the version by 1 then recompile

Answer (score 0):

If you use ProGuard you must edit **proguard-rules.pro**

Add this line to end.
My SugarRecords ( models ) in **models** folder.

```
-keep class com.username.appname.models.** { *; }
```

And disable **Instant Run** function in Android Studio.
I wrote a tutorial for SugarORM installation [here](http://mehmethanoglu.com.tr/tips/15-activedroid-ve-sugarorm-1.5-android-studio-2.2-kullanimi.html)